# Checking Cell Properties for Collision

Tags: java, android, libgdx, 2d-games

I have a tileMap that I created in Tiled and  gave certain tiles properties such as "blocked". In my libGDX code, I place StaticTiledMapTiles all around my map. Here's my question, do map properties created in Tiled carry over to StaticTiledMapTiles that were previously not in the map? I was thinking of doing this or just using simple Rectangles. To test if the player sprite is touching a tile, I was going to use this code. This code is in the sprite class. Note every unit equals a tile.

```
TiledMapTileLayer cur = (TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get(2);
TiledMapTileLayer.Cell cell = new TiledMapTileLayer.Cell();

if(cur.getCell(Math.round(getX()),Math.round(getY())).getTile().getProperties().containsKey("mushroom")){
     Gdx.app.log("Collision","Collision");
}
```